# Send invites from one guild to another

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I am developing a way to generate a single use invite from one guild and send the invite to someone’s dms from another guild. So the command would be !invite <@user> and it would (again) generate 1 single use from a different server and send it to someone’s dms in another sever. I have a code done already but it seems to be bugging a little. Any help would be nice (discord.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, you got a nice idea, but this is against the Discord Developer ToS, since advertising via the Discord API is NOT ALLOWED.

One thing you could do it using .createInvite method, so basically you get a particular channel, which you could do by

```js
const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.type === "text").first()
```

So that would give you your channel (might wanna check if there isn't any). .createInvite is valid too but it is kinda not suggested

```js
const invite = channel.createInvite({
    maxUses: 1,
    // temporary: true,
    // If you want your invite to give Temp membership then uncomment the previous comment
});
```

Then you can just do

```js
targetUser.send(invite);
```